# LDAP add element error 0x20E7

Tags: ldap

I try to add en element in my AD (in a windows server 2012 R2), in this case, an OU.

```
dn: OU=Utilisateurs,DC=ad2012,DC=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Utilisateurs
distinguishedName: OU=Utilisateurs,DC=ad2012,DC=local
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20100505144625.0Z
whenChanged: 20160228202724.0Z
uSNCreated: 20604
uSNChanged: 3216001
name: Utilisateurs
objectGUID:: 9ulxzk4nGEiW6/dQ+SENDA==
objectCategory: CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ad2012,DC=local
dSCorePropagationData: 20160215205431.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000001.0Z
```

I use the Unix commande to add this element :

```
ldapadd \
    -H ldaps://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:636 \
    -D "Admin@ad2012.local" \
    -w "XXXX" \
    -f testAdd
```

(I tried without SSL too)
Everytime I try, I got this error :

> adding new entry "OU=Utilisateurs,DC=ad2012,DC=local"
>   ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
>       additional info: 000020E7: SvcErr: DSID-031531BE, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

```
ERROR_DS_SECURITY_ILLEGAL_MODIFY
8423 (0x20E7)
The modification was not permitted for security reasons.
```

I don't know how to solve my problem... I achieve to extract the data of my AD, and to add users.
The account used to add elements is the administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use:

```
dn: OU=Utilisateurs,DC=ad2012,DC=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Utilisateurs
```

And maybe, depending on how you are creating the entry:
instanceType: 4

ALL of the following are Generally considered System (operational) attributes and should not be included within an add:

```
distinguishedName: OU=Utilisateurs,DC=ad2012,DC=local
whenCreated: 20100505144625.0Z
whenChanged: 20160228202724.0Z
uSNCreated: 20604
uSNChanged: 3216001
name: Utilisateurs
objectGUID:: 9ulxzk4nGEiW6/dQ+SENDA==
objectCategory: CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ad2012,DC=local
dSCorePropagationData: 20160215205431.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000001.0Z
```

-jim

Comment: Do you have a source where I can find thoses rows ? I just found thoses rows : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/276382 Thanks for your reply

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx shows each attribute. Those with System-Only=True should NOT be in an import ot an add.

Answer (score 1):

I just have to remove the "objectGUID" row...
Searching 4 hours and found a solution 40 minutes after asking the question...